# Shortage on UITableView cell count

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am currently using two prototype cells to have my collectionView in top cell moving horizontally while all other cells moves vertical. It's still short one cell count at the bottom and I can't seem to figure out why.

This is the code. Can you point out where the issue is please?

```
//Mark:- Data arrays

var dataArray: [String] = ["c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"]
var cellArray: [String] = ["10","11","12","13","14","15"]

//Mark:- UITableView Delegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell2.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: cellArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell2
    }
}

//Mark:- UICollectionView Delegate

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InsideCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! InsideCollectionViewCell

    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: dataArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Comment: By shortage you mean instead of 6 CustomTableViewCell you have 5 CustomTableViewCell and 1 MainTableViewCell ?

Comment: Could it be that your arrays are different lengths?

Comment: Yeah I would like to have 7 cells in total, 1 with the horizontal scrolling and the next 6 cells should store the cellArray values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want your table view to contain the values in your `cellArray` array plus one extra special row at index 0.

In order to do this you need to indicate that there is an extra row and your indexing needs to account for the extra row.

But a simpler approach is to use multiple sections in your table view. Use section 0 for the extra special row and use section 1 for the values in your `cellArray`.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == 0 ? 1 : cellArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell2.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: cellArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell2
    }
}
```

Make sure you adjust for the use of multiple sections in any other table view method you may implement (such as `didSelectRowAt`, etc.).

For the sake of comparison, here is how you would need to change your code if you want all of the rows in one section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellArray.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell2.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: cellArray[indexPath.row - 1])

        return cell2
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestions but I only get left with 2 sections at all times and less cells

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly? Perhaps you missed one of the small changes I made. Assuming you use the first set of code I posted, you should get two sections. The 1st section will have the one extra row and the 2nd section will have all of the values from your `cellArray` array.

Comment: My bad I had only seen the first section when I did it, it works magnificently I really really appreciate it